To show a homomorphism defined on a finite group $G$ is an identity homomorphism on $G$.
Let $G$ be a finite group.Let $f:G\rightarrow G$ be a group homomorphism.Define $H=\{g\in G:f(g)=g\}$ such that $o(H)>\frac {o(G)}{2}$.Then $f(x)=x$,$\forall x \in G$.

I tried to prove the above statement as follows:
Let $H=\{g\in G:f(g)=g\}$.Claim:$H$ is a subgroup of $G$.Proof:As if $e$ is the identity element of $G$ then $e\in H$ therefore $H\ne \emptyset$.Now let $a,b\in H$. Then $f(ab^{-1})=f(a)f(b^{-1})=ab^{-1}$$\implies ab^{-1}\in H$Therefore $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.Now as order of a subgroup divides order of a group and if order of $H$ is more than half of the order of $G$ then it can not divide order of $G$ unless $H=G$.So $f(x)=x$ $\forall x\in G$.A similar proof is also proposed here(In case of automorphisms),but the proof suggests that automorphism is not necessary to prove that $f$ is an identity function on G.I was wondering if there is any other standard proofs other than this.

Yes this is good. Fine work!

"For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions." See here.

"If order of H
is more than half of the order of the group then H=G
." See Lagrange's theorem here

Yes, what you did is correct.
Just a minor issue: "if order of $H$ is more than half of the order of G then it can not divide order of $G$" should be followed by unless $|H|=|G|$.
Another way is to use the range of $f$ is a subgroup, and since the range contains all of $g$ that is fixed by $f$, therefore the range has more than half of the elements, hence must be the full group $G$.
A third way is to show the kernel of $f$ is trivial. If not, take $g\in\ker f\setminus\{e\}$, then $h\mapsto hg$ is a bijection of $G$. If $h$ is fixed by $f$, then $h=f(h)=f(hg)\not=hg$, hence each element that is fixed by $f$ is paired with one that is not, so the number of fixed points of $f$ cannot exceed half of $G$.

$f(hg)=f(h) f(g)=0$?

Your third proof is extraordinary.

Since $G$ is not assumed to be abelian, we shall use $1$ or $e$, not $0$, and $f(h)f(g)=f(h)e=f(h)=h$

Yes sir,you are right.

$f(h)=f(hg)$ how you deduced this step?Although you have defined a bijection from $G$ to $Gg$ but it need be true that $h=hg$ but in the case if i call the above bijection from $G$ to Gg as $m$ then $m(h)=hg$.

@SandeepTiwari $g$ is taken from the kernel, hence $f(g)=e$ and $f(hg)=f(h)f(g)=f(h)$. And ${x: f(x)=x}$ is bijective to ${xg: f(x)=x}$. These two are disjoint (as we have shown the second set doesn't contain any fixed point of $f$) and if the former has more than half of the elements, so does the second, in total more than $|G|$, a contradiction.

Sir can you link this question with that duplicate question or delete this question permanently so others can not downvote.

@SandeepTiwari I don't know how to do either of those things. I often disagree with how people downvote or close a question on the platform (many are unreasonably aggressive in my opinion), but it is what it is and we all have to learn to live with it.
